# How can I use a script to create users in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm in the process of setting up mongodb, and we use puppet to control the configuration of our servers.

I've got most things setup how I need them, but I need to create the user inside the mongo database.

I know how to do this using the mongo shell, and I know that I can do it using javascript / a .js using the command

```
db.addUser("username", "password"[, readOnly])
```

However, I have been unable to find a solid example of what is needed to do this in javascript. More to the point, I need to be able to add a user from the command line, using some sort of shell script.

If someone could

a) point me to some solid examples of using javascript with mongoDB and

b) how can I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mongo's cli tells you itself how to use it with a js file

```
$ mongo --help
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.3
usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]
...
```

**usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]**

For example:

```
$ echo 'db.addUser("guest", "passwordForGuest", true);' > file.js
$ mongo mydb file.js
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.3
connecting to: mydb
{ "n" : 0, "connectionId" : 1, "err" : null, "ok" : 1 }
{
    "user" : "guest",
    "readOnly" : true,
    "pwd" : "b90ba46d452e5b5ecec64cb64ac5fd90",
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fbea2b013aacb728754fe10")
}
```

**Udpate:**
**db.addUser deprecated since 2.6**
https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/method/db.addUser/

use `db.createUser` instead:

```
// file.js
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "guest",
    pwd: "passwordForGuest",
    roles: [ { role: "read", db: "mydb" } ]
  }
)
```

`$ mongo mydb file.js`

Comment: How can roles be assigned in this way?  The shell addUser command seems inconsistent -- it only takes a single document parameter. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/
Are there API docs for Javascript (vs. the shell). The link here: http://api.mongodb.org/js/current/ contains no actual documentation.

Comment: You should ask a question,  if you have a question,  as that's not related to this answer.

Comment: It seems `addUser()` has been deprecated and has been replaced by `createUser()`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more simple and elegant solution:

```
echo 'db.addUser("<username>", "<password>");' | mongo <database>
```

Tested with MongoDB 2.4.8

Answer (score 3):

I know AD7six has already given an issue but when I try, I obtain a user with a database authentication 'test'.
So I added one command before create User to choose this authentication database.

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('myDataBase');
db.createUser(
 {
   user: "myUser",
   pwd: "myPwd",
   roles: [
    { role: "readWrite", db: "myDataBase" }
   ]
 }
);
```

The authentication database and the database used by the user can be different.
The command "getSiblingDB(dataBase)" (Javascript) is an alternative to "use dataBase" (Shell)